# Getting all permutations of a word or number

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation

Using LINQ or the old-fashioned approach, how can I get all permutations of a word/number (without using an external API)?

Eg ab = ab, ba,
abc = acb, bac, etc

Is this a specific computer science problem like image recognition, etc?

Comment: search google for keyword "next permutation" algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a fantastic [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163513.aspx) on this very subject that should help you get started. This is a very well-studied [computer science problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_in_computing). For additional reference, see fascicles of [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html) Volume 4. In particular, check out [Pre-fascicle 2B](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc2b.ps.gz) which exactly covers the problem of generating all permutations.